# Poco::DOMParser and wstring

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, poco-libraries, wstring

Is there any way to make`Poco::DOMParser` work with `std::wstring`?

I build pocoXML lib with defined `XML_UNICODE` and `XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T`. Now
I'm trying to compile code like this:

```
Poco::XML::DOMParser parser;
std::wstring xml = getXml(); //Init string with xml document

// Cannot compile, cause parseString wants only std::string
// not wstring
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::XML::Document> document = parser.parseString(xml);
```

`Poco::XML::SaxParser` can parse `std::wstring` and `Poco::XML::DOMParser` use SAXParser to build document. So I have no idea why I cannot pass std::wstring to parseString.

Maybe I cannot use parseString, but there is another way to parse std::wstring with DOMParser?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use std::wstring on Windows with only `XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T` defined. On POSIX platforms, you'll have to make sure that wchar_t is 2 bytes wide (check the `__SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__` define). It is a good practice to use XMLString, which is appropriately defined from `std::basic_string`, based on `XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T` define.

There is a problem that prevents Poco::XML compilation with `XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T`, though. Github [issue](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/463) has been created and the problem is now [fixed](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/commit/ba0d9830eb28d2a6660357934556dcc80b1e03a2) in the develop branch for [1.5.3 release](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues?milestone=7&state=open).

Comment: Me and my coworkers fixed this problem by using toXMLString & fromXMLString to convert std::string. Probably this is not correct. (parseString method still unavailable). I guess that no one use DOMParser for wstring, so this functionality is not available.   
 Also we faced the same problem (cannot compile with XML_UNICODE and XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T) with PocoUtils/XMLconfiguration.cpp

Comment: You can convert back and forth from/to std::string as long as you make sure that std::string is UTF-8 encoded. You will, of course, pay some performance penalty for conversions.Util depends on XML, so if XML build is broken with `XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T`, Util won't build either. The above mentioned fix should take care of that.